# Bash & MySQL. Need a way to query database once and sort by Account ID

Tags: mysql, bash, loops

OK so I have about 200 unique ACCOUNT_ID's in a database table that looks like this...

ACCOUNT_ID, FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3

Currently I have a bash script that gets all ACCOUNT_ID's first then loops through each ID dumping the data to a CSV file.  Pretty straight forward.  Problem is the database has become HUGE over the past few years and my script has become inefficient since its looping 200 times which is 200 queries to the database.  Currently each query can take 5 to 60 minutes each which is no good for a script that runs daily.

Is there a way I can query the database once instead of 200 times and sort the data into CSVs by ACCOUNT_ID?

My script looks like this today:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get all ACCOUNT_ID's from database as $a
for a in `echo "select ACCOUNT_ID from table;" | $MYSQL -u $USER -p$PASS -h $HOST $DBNAME -N`

# Loop through database
do

  # For each ACCOUNT_ID query database and dump to CSV file
  $MYSQL -u $USER -p$PASS -h $HOST $DBNAME -s -N -e "select ACCOUNT_ID,FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3 FROM table WHERE ACCOUNT_ID=${a};" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' >> /path/${a}-filename.csv

done
```

Comment: is that the original script ?? this cant work. "table" is a keyword in MySQL and you cant use it as table name without backticks. So please post your real script that we can help you

Comment: why do you append the output always to your file ">> /path/${a}-filename.csv". is this correct ?? Do you want to have a own file for each ID with the old data from the last run ?

Comment: The script and query is a bit more complex with lots of table joins so NO this is not the actual script.  Just a toned down version of the same thing.

Comment: Yes I do need a CSV file for each ACCOUNT ID

Comment: and also the old DATA in this file (always append) ?

Comment: My script runs daily and writes the CSV to the correct path location (not included in sample or needed).  So yes old data is not needed.  In the real MySQL query there is a WHERE matching the DATE also not shown here.

Comment: Use [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) with the right options and you can emit well-formed CSV directly from MySQL. No need for `sed`.

Comment: Yes I try and use that why I can.  In this case we had some issues with that which is why we used sed.   Not really concerned about that right now more interested is how to solve with 1 query instead of 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you not want us to show the real script. Here is a little help

You only must pipe the output to awk to split it into separate files like this and also you only use **ONE QUERY**

```
 $MYSQL -u $USER -p$PASS -h $HOST $DBNAME -s -N -e \
 "select ACCOUNT_ID,FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3 FROM table ORDER BY ACCOUNT_ID;" | \
    sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' | \
    awk -F, '{gsub(/"/, "", $1); print > "ppp/"$1"-filename.csv"}'
```

Comment: That worked PERFECTLY.  Thank you.  One minor question.  It saved the CSV file as: "2"-filename.csv (2 was the account ID).  How can I save the file without the quotes in the filename?

Comment: try this : awk -F, '{gsub(/"/, "", $1); print > "ppp/"$1"-filename.csv"}'

Comment: have changed it in my answer

Comment: Is this possible using the MySQL OUTFILE too?

Comment: hey  Bernd I just found an issue that I didnt see until now.  When I look at my CSV file I am missing the leading " before my data.  See below.

Comment: 4 "2858" "2017-03-05 00:08:15" "2017-03-05 00:09:05" "15869971000" "" "Anonymous" "Anonymous" 

I need a " in front of the 4 so Excel see everything correctly.  Any help would be great.  Thank you.

Comment: Also lost my commas

Comment: try this: **awk 'BEGIN { FS= ","; }{  print > "path/" gensub(/"/, "", "g" ,$1) "-filename.csv"}'**

Comment: Bernd you are amazing!  Thank you so much.